# Help with Split Screen bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, browser, split, bookmarklet

I have the following bookmarklet code that splits a web browser window into 2 frames to see different web pages side by side. The code works fine on some web sites but others it does not work, it will divide the window, start loading up the 1st frame then break out of frames and go to a full page. One particular site this occurs is on http://www.cbssports.com, the code asks for 2 URL's if I put in the CBS URL and then say Yahoo.com URL it will fill up with the CBS site. Any ideas why this is happening? Below is the code:

javascript:A14nH=location.href;L3f7=prompt('Choose File 1',A14nH);R1Gh7=prompt('Choose File 2',L3f7);if(L3f7&&R1Gh7){Fr4Q='\n';Fr4Q+='\n';Fr4Q+='';with(document){write(Fr4Q);void(close())}}else{void(null)}

Answer (score 3):

Line 103 (at the time of writing this answer) of http://www.cbssports.com/ is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* Window Management */ if(top != self){window.open(location.href, '_top');}</script>
```

That's pretty much saying if the top level window isn't CBS Sports (in other words, if it's framed), to open CBS Sports in the top level window, replacing whatever was framing it.

Comment: Is there any way around this or am I stuck with it and just have to use 2 browser windows when on this site? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this can be answered then, why does the same code work in the Opera browser? Firefox and Chrome does not allow the code to work. Opera is not my browser of choice, that's why I am trying to fix the code to get it to work in one of the other 2 browsers.

Comment: @BobC: I don't know why it doesn't work in Opera. (I don't use it either.) I might consider that a bug. Perhaps Opera is just trying to be compatible with some old browser's flaws?

Comment: Well I'll keep pressing on, thanks for your answers, at least I know it isn't my code.